# To execute key press from within bash

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, readline

How do we execute/simulate key press from within bash line code script?

e.g. `alt-L` a shortcut preset with a readline code is needed to be triggered in such bash line code
How to achieve it?

Comment: I don't understand the sentence "alt-L a shortcut preset with a readline code is needed to be such in bash line code". Can you maybe rephrase?

Comment: If you're using an X server, you could use something like [xdotool](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool)  with, e.g,  `xdotool key alt+l` to simulate a keypress, but you mentioned "readline" which makes me think you want to do something just within the shell or terminal, but like Marcus, I don't understand the sentence.

Comment: Consider updating your question and mention not only that you want `Alt+L` to be triggered by a script but what you expect this to achieve by doing this, i.e., what the underlying issue is that you are trying to solve. This may make it easier to answer your question in a way that is more helpful to you.